# How to keep the formulas and clear the content in Excel using VB.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, export-to-excel, vba

**Aim to Achieve :**

> - I have a range of data that I want to replace with new data.
> - So, I want to clear the old data and replace it with new data.
> - But the formulas in the old data are also required to work on new data.

I did the following :

```
Private Sub updateData(ByRef sheet As Excel.Worksheet, ByVal dataRow As String, ByRef data As Object)
    Dim range As Excel.Range
    downRange(sheet, dataRow).ClearContents()  // Note this !!
    // Both data and formulas are lost due to this.
    // What shall I use instead of this to retain the formulas in the first row.
    range = sheet.Range(dataRow.Substring(0, dataRow.Length - 1) + (data.GetLength(0) + 1).ToString())
    range.Value2 = data
    // If the 1st row still has the formulas, then I can do AutoFill for this new data.
End Sub

Private Function downRange(ByRef sheet As Excel.Worksheet, ByVal rangeString As String)
    Dim range As Excel.Range
    range = sheet.Range(rangeString)
    range = sheet.Range(range, range.End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown))
    Return range
End Function
```

**But, the problem is :**

> - **The formulas are getting lost.** (Obviously)
> - I want to retain the formulas in the first row, so that I can then do AutoFill
> - Can you suggest some solution ?

**Demo of required results:**

> OLD data :

```
  |   A      |  B  |  C  |
1 |   H1     |  H2 |  H3 |
2 |   =B2+C2 |  5  |  9  |   Therefore, A2 = 14
3 |   =B3+C3 |  7  |  2  |   Therefore, A3 = 9
```

> I want to replace data and retain the formulas, so that (New data) :

```
  |   A      |  B  |  C  |
1 |   H1     |  H2 |  H3 |
2 |   =B2+C2 |  4  |  6  |   Therefore, A2 = 10
3 |   =B3+C3 |  3  |  5  |   Therefore, A3 = 8
```

> And the given call is `updateData(sheet, "A2:C2", dataFromDB)`
>
> How can I save the formulas but change the data without changing function call ?

Comment: In which cells are your formulas?

Comment: Actually the old data had the formulas in every row, but its like if the formulas in the **first row** i.e. `"A2:F2"` can be retained, then I can `AutoFill` them to rest of the rows.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.  Which cells do you want to replace with data?  Which do you want to keep?  If you don't want the formulas to be lost, don't delete them.

Comment: **Alright.. I am altering the question to make it more clear.. !!**

Comment: Can you please add an example of one cell that contains old data (and what it contains), and the sample of what the new data is, and what result you are looking for? I'm really confused but would like to help.

Comment: **Alright.. Adding this information to the Question !**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're almost there - it looks like you just need to start the clearing one row down from the top.

Assuming you have access to the Range.Offset method (I don't have an easy way to test this from Vb.Net but I see no reason why it shouldn't be available) then you should be able to just shift your starting cell:

```
Private Function downRange(ByRef sheet As Excel.Worksheet, ByVal rangeString As String)
    Dim range As Excel.Range
    range = sheet.Range(rangeString).Offset(1, 0) // Here's the extra piece
    range = sheet.Range(range, range.End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown))
    Return range
End Function
```

Comment: I saw a solution on MSDN : 
`range.Offset(1, 0).Resize(range.Rows.Count - 1, range.Columns.Count)`

So, what about Resize ?
I am not able to understand this !

Comment: @Yugal - that code's slightly different: it takes an already-defined range (like the result of your original `downRange` function) and adjusts it to exclude the first row. `Offset` moves the whole range, so `Resize` is applied to move the end back to where it was. It's common when `UsedRange` or `CurrentRegion` is applied to grab a contiguous block of cells and, for example, remove data in a table while leaving the headers intact.

Comment: Now, I understand.. ! Let me try and then i will revert back !

Comment: Seem to have solved my issue.. though I used `Resize` in my implementation.. !!
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and used this logic when I cleared the cells. The below snippet clears cells in colums A-C & F from rows 2-1000 except row 5. Use this when you want fined grained control over what you want cleared. :

```
Const clearCells = "A?:C?,F?"

Sub clearCells()
For i = 2 To 1000
If i <> 5 Then
Range(Replace(clearCells, "?", i)).ClearContents
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

A simpler method would be this to clear Columns A-C and F from rows 2-2000:

```
    Range ("A2:C2000,F2:F2000").ClearContents
```

Lastly, to rewrite your program, you can loop through the range instantiate a new range and add cells to the range only if they do not have a formula like this:

```
Private Function downRange(ByRef sheet As Excel.Worksheet, ByVal rangeString As String)
Dim inRange As Excel.range
Dim outRange As range
Set inRange = sheet.range(rangeString)
Set inRange = sheet.range(inRange, inRange.End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown))
Dim r As range
For Each r In inRange
  If Left(r.Formula, 1) <> "=" Then
    If outRange Is Nothing Then
    Set outRange = r
    Else
    Set outRange = Application.Union(outRange, r)
    End If
  End If
Next r
downRange = outRange
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the formulas in the first row, don't select the first row for deletion.  Pass `"A3:F3"` to the function.

As for autofill, use the `Range.FormulaR1C1` property.  Read the `FormulaR1C1` from the first cell and write the same value to `FormulaR1C1` in the remaining cells.

Comment: No.. I can't do that.. I have to make changes in my function only.
Input to the function is logically independent to the function and can-not change.